# Definition of energy in relation to thermal energy

Tags: thermodynamics

Energy is often defined as the capacity of a system to do work.

How does this definition apply to thermal energy?

Work is done by displacing an object under a force. But under what force is displacement occurring on the microscopic level?

Answer (score 0):

Take a large container of air. Plug the opening with a stopper with weight sitting on the top of stopper. The work done could be to move the weight upwards due to increase in pressure. Then work equals force times distance. The pressure is due to movement of the gas filing the container.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal energy can and does do work.
Thermal energy is the energy possessed by a system due to the motion of particles within that system. Thermal energy is a type of energy, where indeed "energy" can be defined as "the capacity or ability to do work". And yes, mechanical work is the movement of an object due to an applied force. Therefore, can thermal energy be described as the ability/capacity of a system to cause movement of an object due to an "applied force"? The answer is yes.

Consider now a system which contains a cylinder and inside that cylinder is a piston where a certain gas is enclosed by the cylinder and piston. As stated before, this gas has energy due to the motion of the gas molecules. If we heat this gas, we increase the thermal energy and consequently the piston moves. Clearly, *the energy of the gas has done work on the piston*. This is an example of a "force (manifested by an increase in pressure) causing a displacement" as you stated.